# Is there a neater alternative to if-let to call a function on an Optional?

Tags: swift, functional-programming, option-type

I often find myself with constructions like the following:

```
let maybeValue: SomeType? = ...
if let definitelyValue = maybeValue {
    return someFunc(definitelyValue)
} else {
    return nil
}
```

If `someFunc` were a method, I'd simply use chaining (`maybeValue?.someMethod`), and if my goal were a non-optional via default I'd use the nil-coalescing operator (`maybeValue ?? defaultValue`), but the if-let above is significantly less tidy than these options.

Comment: Did you search for a duplicate?

Comment: @Sulthan I did, but apparently not with the right wording! I agree that this is a duplicate of the question Martin linked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **map** or **flatMap** on Optional types. flatMap basically evaluates the closure passed to it if and only if the value exist.

Here is a sample,

```
let maybeValue: String? = "awesome swift"

let val = maybeValue.flatMap { $0.uppercased() }
```

Answer (score -2):

You could ignore the intermediate value by using _

```
let maybeValue: SomeType? = ...
if let _ = maybeValue {
    return someFunc(maybeValue!)
} else {
    return nil
}
```

Which at least saves having to use another variable.

Comment: Why the down vote? I am answering the question and providing a slight advantage.

Comment: What's the point of `if let` if you are going to force unwrap it?

Comment: You have checked that it is safe to do so.

Comment: `providing a slight advantage` Which one? You replace a variable name with "_" and then you add a character to another one. How is that "neater" than the normal way? And makes you unwrap the value *twice* which is not optimal at all.

Comment: I'm really not a fan of this approach - I'm of the opinion that forced unwraps are generally a code smell. If I was that worried about the variable, I'd honestly prefer to just reuse the name: `if let value = value { return someFunc(value) }`.